# Spring, Dependency Injection inquiry

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

From the book "Spring in Action", I have seen this configuration xml file:

```
<bean id="knight" class="com.springinaction.knights.BraveKnight">
<constructor-arg ref="quest" />
Inject quest bean
</bean>
```

What exactly is  `<constructor-arg ref="quest" />`? Does it mean that each time I call quest as a reference in a constructor it fetches a BraveKnight?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML snippet you have is called a **bean definition**. You are declaring a bean which Spring can generate for you.

Using `<constructor-arg>` tells Spring to use a `com.springinaction.knights.BraveKnight` constructor which accepts an argument of whatever type the bean referenced by the id `quest` is and inject that bean in the constructor call. This is called `constructor based dependency injection`. [It is covered here.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection)

Given two classes

```
class Foo {}

class Bar {
    private Foo foo;
    public Bar (Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

and the following bean definitions

```
<bean id="foo" class="Foo" />

<bean id="bar" class="Bar">
    <constructor-arg ref="foo">
</bean>
```

A `Foo` bean will be created with id `foo`. That bean will be used when invoking the `Bar` constructor to create the bean with id `bar`. Remember that this is all done through reflection.

Comment: +1, I would put a simple code example to it. It will make undestanding more clear.